# Has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check - .NET CORE

Tags: .net-core, cors

we want to enable CORS but we have a error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.*****.ikanbi.com/appHub/negotiate' from origin 'http://web.******.ikanbi.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In localhost it's works but went we publish error our code :

> ```
> services.AddCors(options =>
>         {
>             options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
>                 builder => builder
>                 .AllowAnyMethod()
>                 .AllowAnyHeader()
>                 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://web.******.ikanbi.com").SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
>                 .AllowCredentials()
>                 );
>         });
> ```

> app.UseCors("AllowAll");

Help !

Comment: how do you know it is CORS error, it is nowhere mention in your error

Answer (score -1):

I would really need more details to help you accurately.

However, with the information provided, I can recommend that you add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header settings

e.g.:

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4200' always;`

Comment: In localhost it's works but with IIS always the error.